# How to run number statements as sequence with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to running some statements as sequence with javascript and wrote this codes but did not work.Please advice

```
    var repeat = true;

    var bootstrap = false;
    function fifteen() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].setAttribute("style", "width:50%");
        //document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width = "width:50%";

    }

    function sixteen() {
        if ( bootstrap != true) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].setAttribute("style", "width:70%");

        }
    }

    var i = 0;
    function onehundred() {
        if (bootstrap === true) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].setAttribute("style", "width:100%");
            console.log(++i);
        }
    };

    function clear() {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width === "100%") {
                clearInterval(r1);
                clearInterval(r2);
                clearInterval(r3).done(function() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("content").className = "";
                });

            }
    }
    //repeet this work 

      var r1=  setInterval(function () { sixteen(); }, 100);
      var r2=  setInterval(function () { onehundred(); }, 100);
      var r3 = setInterval(function () { clear(); }, 100);
```

Error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: Please provide a full example of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) returns `undefined`. You can't just chain `.done` methods off of anything in JavaScript.

`clearInterval` is *synchronous*, regardless. Just place those statements after it.

```
clearInterval(r3);
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("content").className = "";
```

If you really wanted this functionality, you would need to override the existing `clearInterval`, but this is borderline stupid, creating confusing looking code that implies asynchronous flow where there is none.

```js
(function () {
  var old = clearInterval;
  
  clearInterval = function (id) {
    old(id);
    
    return {
      done: function (fn) {
        fn();
      }
    };
  };
}());
```